# Symfony - Doctrine or Twig - Sum of several time

Tags: php, loops, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'd like to know how I can sum  several time (hh: mm: ss) with symfony doctrine ...

Knowing that I get my entity like this:

```
    public function validationFicheTutorielAction(Request $request) {
        $id_tutoriel = $request->get('id_tutoriel');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tutoriel = $em->getRepository('Video2LearnBddBundle:Tutoriel')->findOneById($id_tutoriel);
    }
```

I finally obtained a "tutorial" that contains several "chapters" containing themselves the "Videos". Each video has a duration, I'd like to sum each  video time duration (from all chapters together ...)

The response `"$ tutorial"` may look like this:

```
Tutorial       
    [0] Chapter         
         [0] Video         
               duration : 01:24:01         
         [1] Video         
               duration : 0:41:41         
    [1] Chapter         
         [0] Video         
               duration : 04:11:01         
         [1] Video
               duration : 00:29:41         
         [2] Video         
               duration : 00:33:41         
    [2] Chapter         
         [0] Video         
               duration : 02:11:09         
         [1] Video         
               duration : 00:02:01         
         [2] Video         
               duration : 00:21:55
```

is there an existing or another function to sum all these time for the total duration ?

I suppose the solution is to use a foreach in a foreach and then add each duration but I don't know how to do that in doctrine...

thanks :)

Comment: Is the duration of a chapter saved in database? If yes, take a look to Doctrine's [lifecycle events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html). And if no, just add an attribute to your Chapter entity and do the calculation in your controller (or in a service to fit with best practices).

Answer (score 0):

There is a merge function in symfony to merge all videos in one array and iterate over them.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html

In my opinion you should fetch the duration recusivly in your controller and pass the duration as variable.

Otherwise you could store the duration as argument in you Tutorial entity and every time a video is added, the duration of the tutorial is incremented by the duration amount of the video, but this puts more logic into your entity so I would prefer to fetch the time in the controller recursivly, or in twig template by merging and iterating over the merged array.